# How to prove a relation at compile-time in Lean?

Tags: dependent-type, type-theory, lean

Say I have a type:

```
inductive is_sorted {α: Type} [decidable_linear_order α] : list α -> Prop
| is_sorted_zero : is_sorted []
| is_sorted_one : Π (x: α), is_sorted [x]
| is_sorted_many : Π {x y: α} {ys: list α}, x < y -> is_sorted (y::ys) -> is_sorted (x::y::ys)
```

And it's decidable:

```
instance decidable_sorted {α: Type} [decidable_linear_order α] : ∀ (l : list α), decidable (is_sorted l)
```

If I have a particular list:

`def l1: list ℕ := [2,3,4,5,16,66]`

Is it possible to prove that it's sorted at "compile time"; to produce an `is_sorted l1` at the top level?

I've tried `def l1_sorted: is_sorted l1 := if H: is_sorted l1 then H else sorry`, but I don't know how to show the latter case is impossible. I've also tried the `simp` tactic but that didn't seem to help.

I can prove it with `#reduce`, but it doesn't possible to assign the output of that to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `dec_trivial` to prove `l1_sorted`. This will try to infer an instance of `decidable (is_sorted l1)`, and if the instance evaluates to `is_true p`, it will reduce to `p`.

Comment: How would I go about writing it? `lemma l1_sorted: is_sorted l1  := by dec_trivial` doesn't work, nor does `by dec_trivial (is_sorted l1)`.

Comment: `lemma l1_sorted: is_sorted l1 := dec_trivial`

Comment: This seems to fail with: `infer type failed, unknown variable
  _inst_1
of_as_true : ∀ {c : Prop} [h₁ : decidable c], as_true c → c`

Comment: Actually, turns out my problem was I had `instance decidable_sorted` instead of `instance decidable_is_sorted`, I didn't realise the lookup was name-based, sorry.